# Late Answers review audits are too hard

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, late-answers

I have been always reviewing the "Late Answers" queue with fear. I always click out the question to see if the answer is deleted (to determine if it's an audit, and to checkout other answers).

Late Answers audits are too hard for the following reason:

- The audits are mainly picked from "Close Vote" queue. This means that those audits don't reflect the characteristics of "Late Answer". Such as:

  - Duplicating current answer (can only be checked **by viewing all answers**)
  - Low quality answer

  These are hard to flag:

  > Any post that attempts to answer the question, however badly is still an answer. You can downvote such posts to signal that the answer is a bad answer, but it is still an answer. *[When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)*
- The guidelines are unclear. One thing that I think it needs improvement is the treatment of link-only answers. They're often taken from Low Quality Posts queue, and at there an appropriate reason for deletion exists. However, at LA queue the correct choice is flagging as "low quality post". Low quality posts enters Triage today, and the purpose of flag is less clear than others.

Comment: see [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505/839601)

Comment: Note: low-quality-flagged *answers* go to LQP review on every site, even SO, not to Triage. SO routes only questions to Triage.